# Pivot table to plot sums of dates of each month

Tags: excel, pivot-table

In excel I have a column of days (mm/dd/yyyy) and I want to have a timeline sort of plot showing how many points I have for each month of each year. It's easy to show how many instances a day appears with a pivot table (added a column "Count" with just 1's), and then make a plot for that, but I don't know how to do that with just the month/year.

I tried using the =month and =year functions, and highlighted those columns (with the "Count" column) to make a pivot table, but I'm not sure how to group and plot it the way I want. Here's what it looks like when I have data point sums for month/day/year, I want the same thing but with the month/year:

[image]

And here's my data:
[image]

I'm sorry if this is a really low level problem, I'm a noob at pivot tables and have been trying this all day

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data by month (or other useful options like quarter & year) **IF** values are formatted as actual dates. It looks like yours is formatted as a date but just in case, here are two ways to test...

**A)** Change format of a cell with date to number (this should return a date serial)
**B)** Use `=ISTEXT(Select Cell With Date)` (this should return `FALSE`)

Once valid date format has been verified

1. Click on a date in pivot table
2. Navigate to `Analyze` tab
3. Select `Group Selection`
4. You should get a pop-up asking how you want to group the data. Select `Month`
5. Ensure you are summarizing the points by `Sum` (right click on point cell in pivot and set option at `Summarize Values By`)

If you are using a pivot chart, it will update on refresh to reflect new row groupings (I.E. show monthly sums as you asked for)

Before & After photos below

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can this work across the span of multiple years (in chronological order?)